# Best practice to store sensitive information like vcs or keystore passwords or API keys required during build process in Android studio

Tags: android, architecture

Maybe it is stupid question, but I confused about where such sensitive data like vcs passwords, API keys, keystore passwords need to be stored if I need it to use during build process. Is there some rule or best practice?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in res/Values/Strings.xml and obfuscate that file with proguard
Or better yet keep anything your app doesnt need when running as an environment variable